# Break in for loop, R

Tags: r, for-loop, break

Okay, this is going to seem really stupid but I cant figure out what's wrong for the life of me! Here is my code:

```
for(dist in seq(.1,1,.1)){
 print(dist)
 if(dist==.7){
   break
 }
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
[1] 0.1
[1] 0.2
[1] 0.3
[1] 0.4
[1] 0.5
[1] 0.6
[1] 0.7
[1] 0.8
[1] 0.9
[1] 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a floating point rounding error.  if you print(dist-0.7) there is a difference of 1.110223e-16.

Comment: Thanks Dave2e. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is not getting break because the condition is never met,

Basically you are comparing wrongly the values in the condition...
try this instead:

```
for(dist in seq(.1,1,.1)){
      print(dist)
      if(isTRUE(all.equal(dist,.7))){
         break
    }
}
```

this will print

> [1] 0.1
>   [1] 0.2
>   [1] 0.3
>   [1] 0.4
>   [1] 0.5
>   [1] 0.6
>   [1] 0.7
>
> sh-4.3$

Comment: Thanks! That works. @Dave2e pointed out the floating point error.

Comment: you are welcome... the floating point are a pain in the neck :)